# How do Facebook and Stack Overflow have these amazing features?

Tags: web-applications

I'm really interested in learning how these two things are accomplished:

Facebook: when a user is logged in and just sitting at their news feed, new items automatically show up in the news feed, the red badges for friend requests, messages, and notifications automatically appear, and instant messaging is live. That's a lot of database activity! On top of that, users have the ability to remotely end other sessions, so all of their sessions would have to constantly be checking if they're still valid. With so many users, how does all this work without killing their servers?

Stack Overflow: There are 60+ badges on Stack Overflow based on a wide variety of actions the user does. It seems like it would be extremely complicated to check virtually all of the user's actions to see if it earned them a badge or not. Same question: with so many users, how does all this work without killing their servers?

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: There are scripts that run as background processes on the server to assess the badges earned by users, and a host of other interesting things. Presumably, the actions are recorded as they occur, and the information is saved in the user's profile. Not really all that amazing given modern technology. They don't just have one server sitting behind a cable modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Planning:
```

First step in the process is planning. Facebook or Stackoverflow cannot create a badge today and 2 months down the line, they find a problem. So a detailed planning is done to create a category. I can write long here, but you need some tech; lets move ahead.

```
 Object Oriented:
```

Everything is Object Oriented in these applications. Take for example [Careers.stackoverflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). What ever related to careers is moving around careers. So a huge set of careers, resumes, present users of stackoverflow data is present there. Take for example the badges of the users, they they cannot make it as obeject, it cannot be used by careers sub domain. They create as such the badges object could be used at different applications.

```
I just promoted careers site of stackoverflow. :)
```

.

```
Database:
```

When we talk about database, procedures, triggers, etc also come into account. Just maintaining database is not enough. If one event occurs, one may be required to trigger a database query so it could pull some useful data for that event. Lets say you are answering this same question. While you are still tying, Stackoverflow throws a orange message bar on top stating "1 New answer has been posted". This happens when some user has already posted a answer while you type. Triggers are used here.

```
Ajax:
```

When you want only a small portion of the page to be loaded randomly.

```
Jquery, Ext JS:
```

Used as a nice javascript and good presentation logic.

```
Servers:
```

Within a server they create different node instances, farms at different locations. They route the traffic accordingly to different nodes on server. Thus monitoring which is taking a lot of memory. Then they accordingly allocate new nodes, instances to such traffic.
They use different farms to maintain their database. If one crashes at LA, they pull the data from NY and bring both to the same platform.

```
R&D:
```

Last thing is R&D, without this you cannot keep pace to whats new in market. You have to be upto new techs and developments.

Hope the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know facebook but i would imagine that a javascript polls the server for new news.

Stackoverflow badges are much simpler, they can be caclulated in advance and stored in a users profile to be read when the home page is generated

Comment: How can the badges be calculated in advance? You should read the descriptions for some of the badges [here](http://stackoverflow.com/badges)

Comment: some can be calculate in a batch over night, others are calculated when you do certain actions, like edit a question - none need to be calculated 'live' when a page is displayed

Answer (score 0):

javascript is  one solution
It helps you do things on the fly without reloading

Comment: Right, but querying the database every 30 seconds would be super intense with that many users

Comment: @Nick: Javascript is called by triggers of database. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have *heard* (no verification on my part), HTTP web requests can last forever, and so notifications in Facebook, Gmail, etc. are nothing more than long-lasting requests for "give me the next change that occurs". There's no polling; it's a callback-like mechanism.

Comment: They are known as "long polling".